# Trick for computing limits for functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to compute the limit
$$
\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \sqrt{\left|xy\right| }.
$$

In the  book I'm reading the author states that one can solve this by using polar coordinates:

> Let $x=r\cos\left(\varphi\right), y= r \sin\left(\varphi\right)$
> and consider
> $$
> \lim_{r \to 0} \sqrt{\left|r\cos\left(\varphi\right) \cdot 
> r \sin\left(\varphi\right) \right| } 
> = \lim_{r \to 0} |r| \sqrt{|\cos\left(\varphi \right)\cdot \sin\left(\varphi\right) | } 
> = 0.
> $$

I don't see how this procedure is correct because
$\varphi$ is fixed in the limit computation, meaning one goes only along straight lines and doesn't consider all paths. Shouldn't the expression rather be
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\substack{(r, \varphi)\to (0, \theta)\\\theta \in \mathbb{R}}}
\sqrt{\left|r\cos\left(\varphi\right) \cdot 
r \sin\left(\varphi\right) \right| } 
=\lim_{(r, \varphi)\to \left\{0\right\} \times \mathbb{R}}
 |r| \sqrt{|\cos\left(\varphi \right)\cdot \sin\left(\varphi\right) | } 
= 0
.\end{align*}
The result stays the same in this case since the expression involving
the squareroot is bounded, but I don't think  that the other method is
valid in general.

Comment: I suggest you don't take that book too seriously. It should add another piece of justification: $\sqrt{|xy|}=r\sqrt{|\cos\phi\sin\phi|}\leq r$ (as you mention in your last paragraph). This last inequality gives you a bound independent of $\phi$, and thus we're not making any assumptions about straight lines. But you're right to be cautious; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3803374/568204) for more details.

Comment: @peek-a-boo One question just arose to me: Suppose that I use the authors method with the constraint that if this method yields a limit value that involves $\varphi$ one can conclude that the limit doesn't exist. Would this method be valid then?

Comment: the fact that the limit depends on $\theta$ means the limit's value is affected by which line/path one approaches the origin, so indeed, the limit does not exist in this situation. In any case, I would just suggest avoiding polar coordinates for such problems (the usual cartesian coordinates, and basic inequalities like triangle, AGM, Cauchy-Schwarz are more than enough to deal with such simple functions); they don't really simplify anything and can easily lead to erroneous conclusions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo hm I don't really agree. At least for the exercises I have worked on so far the change to polar coordinates simplified things tremendously. Do you have a method that is similarily quick? (I understood your comment as meaning for general limits. I agree that the above example is very simple and hence polar coordinates aren't really needed here)

Comment: btw the expression $\lim\limits_{(r,\phi)\to \{0\}\times \Bbb{R}}$ is not standard, so I'd avoid it (what you probably meant is that the limit is uniform with respect to $\phi$)

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes, I changed it in the first but the second somehow didn't change.

Comment: Use the trivial estimates $|x|\leq \|(x,y)\|$ and $y\leq \|(x,y)\|$ to get $\sqrt{|xy|}\leq \sqrt{\|(x,y)\|^2}=\|(x,y)\|$ (i.e it's the same thing as $\sqrt{|xy|}\leq r$, but you don't need the detour into polar coordinates). There are many other such trivial estimates (see the comments of my linked answer for example)

Comment: yes, I misunderstood your comment. Thanks a lot for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Please, consider this: We need $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. So we need $(x,y)$ as close to $(0,0)$ we want. That is $(x,y)\in \{(x_1,x_2): ||(x_1,x_2)||<\delta \}=D_{(0,0)}(\delta)$, for appropriately small $\delta >0$. How can we rewrite $D_{(0,0)}(\delta)$ via polar coordinates? We can write $D_{(0,0)}(\delta)=\{(r,φ): r<\delta, φ\in \Bbb R\}$ (it is enough to get $φ\in [0,2π]$). Provided that we have *every* point of $D_{(0,0)}(\delta)$, when $(x,y)\in D_{(0,0)}(\delta)$, we can obtain *any path* round $(0,0)$ and inside $D_{(0,0)}(\delta)$ by sketching the line (=path) we want over the points of disc that we want.-

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is No, and the book answer is perfect: the limit is independent of $φ$, because we need the points $(x,y)$ approaching $(0,0)$ from every path. This can be true only when the polar radius goes to zero *and* the polar angle is anything. If you force the angle $φ$ to approach zero, you get *some* linear paths, these which tend to lie on $x$-axis.

Comment: Polar angle being anything does not mean any path.

Comment: For any φ and for r close to 0 you get any point round (0,0). That means you can get any point inside a disc of centre (0,0) and small radius (φ is rotating anywhere and radius depends on r), which means that you can draw any line inside this disc -"any line" means "any path". A sketch will help.

Comment: Radius of the ball around $(0,0)$ cannot depend on $r$! You should first take a radius that works for every $\varphi$ and every $r$, i. e., the limit should be uniform! What about the paths that are curves? In this case, the polar coordinates might work, but _any angle_ does not mean _any path_! Polar coordinates are usually used to find a path that is a counterexample so as to prove the limit does not exist.

Comment: Of course, if the limit is $0$, it follows that $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ from every path, but you cannot go from the conclusion. You should, at least, mention, $|\cos(\varphi)\sin(\varphi)|\le 1$. Otherwise, the OP will think you are indeed treating $\varphi$ as a constant. You cannot use the consequence of a result to prove a result.

Comment: Please, see the added hint above the answer.